# PHP salt passwords

Tags: passwords, md5, password-protection, sha512

Ok so here is how We do passwords.

note We did change what we salt by.

```
<?


$PASSWORD = $_GET["password"];


$ranNUM = rand(965824, 957873488423748423486483);
$PASSWORD =  hash('sha512', $PASSWORD.$ranNUM.'MONKEY MONEY sad happy 7ab27t8g2hjq8tt 2g y8t 82 t2g edb t7e2gqjcb  t8egsjc byut87qebcjn 87ctyeqcb t78ye jscyt8ique bcg781eghjs btgq78 cbqjg78pqdgj d t87dqgjh bxauy fpqdgs,q vayupf d', TRUE);



for ($i = 1; $i <= $_GET['num']; $i++) {
$PASSWORD =  md5($PASSWORD);
$PASSWORD =  hash('sha512', $PASSWORD.$ranNUM.'MONKEY MONEY sad happy 7ab27t8g2hjq8tt 2g y8t 82 t2g edb t7e2gqjcb  t8egsjc byut87qebcjn 87ctyeqcb t78ye jscyt8ique bcg781eghjs btgq78 cbqjg78pqdgj d t87dqgjh bxauy fpqdgs,q vayupf d', TRUE);
$PASSWORD =  hash('sha512', $PASSWORD.$ranNUM.'MONKEY MONEY sad happy 7ab27t8g2hjq8tt 2g y8t 82 t2g edb t7e2gqjcb  t8egsjc byut87qebcjn 87ctyeqcb t78ye jscyt8ique bcg781eghjs btgq78 cbqjg78pqdgj d t87dqgjh bxauy fpqdgs,q vayupf d', TRUE);
$PASSWORD =  hash('sha512', $PASSWORD.$ranNUM.'MONKEY MONEY sad happy 7ab27t8g2hjq8tt 2g y8t 82 t2g edb t7e2gqjcb  t8egsjc byut87qebcjn 87ctyeqcb t78ye jscyt8ique bcg781eghjs btgq78 cbqjg78pqdgj d t87dqgjh bxauy fpqdgs,q vayupf d', FALSE);
$PASSWORD =  hash('sha512', $PASSWORD.$ranNUM.'MONKEY MONEY sad happy 7ab27t8g2hjq8tt 2g y8t 82 t2g edb t7e2gqjcb  t8egsjc byut87qebcjn 87ctyeqcb t78ye jscyt8ique bcg781eghjs btgq78 cbqjg78pqdgj d t87dqgjh bxauy fpqdgs,q vayupf d', TRUE);
$PASSWORD =  hash('sha512', $PASSWORD.$ranNUM.'MONKEY MONEY sad happy 7ab27t8g2hjq8tt 2g y8t 82 t2g edb t7e2gqjcb  t8egsjc byut87qebcjn 87ctyeqcb t78ye jscyt8ique bcg781eghjs btgq78 cbqjg78pqdgj d t87dqgjh bxauy fpqdgs,q vayupf d', TRUE);
$PASSWORD =  hash('sha512', $PASSWORD.$ranNUM.'MONKEY MONEY sad happy 7ab27t8g2hjq8tt 2g y8t 82 t2g edb t7e2gqjcb  t8egsjc byut87qebcjn 87ctyeqcb t78ye jscyt8ique bcg781eghjs btgq78 cbqjg78pqdgj d t87dqgjh bxauy fpqdgs,q vayupf d', TRUE);
$PASSWORD =  md5($PASSWORD);
$PASSWORD =  hash('sha512', $PASSWORD.$ranNUM.'MONKEY MONEY sad happy 7ab27t8g2hjq8tt 2g y8t 82 t2g edb t7e2gqjcb  t8egsjc byut87qebcjn 87ctyeqcb t78ye jscyt8ique bcg781eghjs btgq78 cbqjg78pqdgj d t87dqgjh bxauy fpqdgs,q vayupf d', TRUE);
$PASSWORD =  hash('sha512', $PASSWORD.$ranNUM.'MONKEY MONEY sad happy 7ab27t8g2hjq8tt 2g y8t 82 t2g edb t7e2gqjcb  t8egsjc byut87qebcjn 87ctyeqcb t78ye jscyt8ique bcg781eghjs btgq78 cbqjg78pqdgj d t87dqgjh bxauy fpqdgs,q vayupf d', FALSE);
$PASSWORD =  hash('sha512', $PASSWORD.$ranNUM.'MONKEY MONEY sad happy 7ab27t8g2hjq8tt 2g y8t 82 t2g edb t7e2gqjcb  t8egsjc byut87qebcjn 87ctyeqcb t78ye jscyt8ique bcg781eghjs btgq78 cbqjg78pqdgj d t87dqgjh bxauy fpqdgs,q vayupf d', TRUE);
$PASSWORD =  md5($PASSWORD);
$PASSWORD =  hash('sha512', $PASSWORD.$ranNUM.'MONKEY MONEY sad happy 7ab27t8g2hjq8tt 2g y8t 82 t2g edb t7e2gqjcb  t8egsjc byut87qebcjn 87ctyeqcb t78ye jscyt8ique bcg781eghjs btgq78 cbqjg78pqdgj d t87dqgjh bxauy fpqdgs,q vayupf d', TRUE);
$PASSWORD =  hash('sha512', $PASSWORD.$ranNUM.'MONKEY MONEY sad happy 7ab27t8g2hjq8tt 2g y8t 82 t2g edb t7e2gqjcb  t8egsjc byut87qebcjn 87ctyeqcb t78ye jscyt8ique bcg781eghjs btgq78 cbqjg78pqdgj d t87dqgjh bxauy fpqdgs,q vayupf d', FALSE);
$PASSWORD =  hash('sha512', $PASSWORD.$ranNUM.'MONKEY MONEY sad happy 7ab27t8g2hjq8tt 2g y8t 82 t2g edb t7e2gqjcb  t8egsjc byut87qebcjn 87ctyeqcb t78ye jscyt8ique bcg781eghjs btgq78 cbqjg78pqdgj d t87dqgjh bxauy fpqdgs,q vayupf d', TRUE);
$PASSWORD =  hash('sha512', $PASSWORD.$ranNUM.'MONKEY MONEY sad happy 7ab27t8g2hjq8tt 2g y8t 82 t2g edb t7e2gqjcb  t8egsjc byut87qebcjn 87ctyeqcb t78ye jscyt8ique bcg781eghjs btgq78 cbqjg78pqdgj d t87dqgjh bxauy fpqdgs,q vayupf d', TRUE);

print $PASSWORD;
print "<br>";

}

//print $PASSWORD;
?>
```

What we do is we send a num say 7 along with the password then we run the encryption 7 times

along with the random number for that user (which is saved in another DB) **NOT ON THE SAME SERVER**

we then have what the password should be.

What do you think is this over kill?

for e.g 123 running twice would get

```
íaªyå`ˆsœA²„†N¸jø¦žÃïªd*hÂ?‘\e½s­&žÉ:Ñl6DïƒÀ`ß,¢‹HÎÌ(üBìð6
```

to make this even safer you could have random paragraphs for each one.

You would need to have it saved somewhere, but would be great if you could just scan a google or bing or any site, and get a random sentence from there site.

Please tell me your thoughts.

Comment: Yes, i do think this is overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an overkill, and I'm not sure it's theoretically sound.

One sound method of making your (salted) password a pain to bruteforce is RSA's PBKDF2.

[Here's a PBKDF2 PHP implementation](http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Encrypting-Passwords-with-PHP-for-Storage-Using-the-RSA-PBKDF2-Standard).

You may also be interested in **Blowcrypt** (similar intent, but using the blowfish algorithms) and **Scrypt** (a nasty little fellow that can be told how much memory you wish the attacker to waste over bruteforcing your password)

Comment: Yes but by have a two random factor it's more secure. RSA v1 which RSA still uses 1999 it was used, has a flaw in it, so I would not trust a system that can be easily broken if you have the time